# Calling R functions in rpy2 error - "argument is missing"

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm facing some issues in using rpy2 package in Python.
Actually, I am trying to call a function called upliftRF (of the library "uplift" in R) by passing some arguments. 
As stated on page 27 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/uplift/uplift.pdf, one of the arguments of the function can be x or a formula that describes the model to fit based on a dataframe ("data" parameter in arguments). 
When executing the code of page 29 in R, everything is running without any problems. However, I have some issues in rpy2. Here is my code :

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
uplift = importr('uplift')
kwargs = {'n': 1000, 'p' : 20, 'rho' : 0, 'sigma' : np.sqrt(2), 'beta.den': 4}
dd = uplift.sim_pte(**kwargs)
ddPD = pandas2ri.ri2py(dd)
ddPD['treat'] = [1 if x==1 else 0 for x in ddPD['treat']]
dd = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(ddPD) 
kwargs2 = {'formula':'y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + trt(treat)',
         'mtry':3,'ntree':200,'split_method':'KL','minsplit':200,'data':dd}

fit1 = uplift.upliftRF(**kwargs2)
```

Then, I get this error :

```
RRuntimeError: Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

However, "x" is not a mandatory parameter of the function.

I guess that the error will be the same for any other R function that has one argument which is not mandatory at all.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: can you try passing the formula as an un-named argument (not a dictionary key)? It is not listed as a `formula=...` but as a simple argument in the documention. Can it be that `x` is actually its name?

Comment: There are two ways of calling this function. The first one is to specify "x" (explanatory variables), "y" (target variable) and "ct" (treatment variable) parameters directly. The second one is to specify a "formula" containing the equation of the model to fit (in the formula, "trt()" must contain the name of the column that corresponds to "ct" (treatment variable)). My goal is to use directly a formula without declaring "x", "y" and "ct" together.

Comment: right, but formula is not a keyword argument according to the documentation. so try to put formula not as `formula = myformula` but as `fit1 = uplift.upliftRF('y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + trt(treat)', **kwargs2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
uplift = importr('uplift')
```

Next, you should be able to use the most-common way to call Python functions because `importr` is "translating" named parameters in the
definition of the R function into syntactically-valid Python names.

```
dd = uplift.sim_pte(n = 1000, p = 20, rho = 0,
                    sigma = np.sqrt(2), beta_den = 4)
```

At this point you appear to have an R `data.frame`. Going to `pandas` to add a column, then back to R, is definitely possible:

```
ddPD = pandas2ri.ri2py(dd) 
ddPD['treat'] = [1 if x==1 else 0 for x in ddPD['treat']]
dd = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(ddPD)
```

However, unless there is a good reason I'd recommend to stick to one conversion scheme when shuttling between `pandas` and `rpy2`. The one
defined in `pandas` or the one defined in `rpy2` as consistency across
is presumably less tested. The error `RRuntimeError: Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors` might come from this.

The alternative to going to `pandas` is to use the eminently expressive R package `dplyr`. `rpy2` is providing a tailored interface to it since version 2.7.0:

```
from rpy2.robjects.lib import dplyr
dd = (dplyr.DataFrame(dd)
      .mutate(treat = 'ifelse(treat==1, 1, 0)')
```

It was already pointed out in your answer that the formula should
be declared as such (formulas are language objects in R, but there is
no equivalent at the language level in Python). When writing this
as a common Python call:

```
fit1 = uplift.upliftRF(formula = robjects.Formula('y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + trt(treat)'),
                       mtry = 3,
                       ntree = 200,
                       split_method = 'KL',
                       minsplit = 200,
                       data = dd)
```