# issues with calling R-function partykit.cforest from Python through rpy2

Tags: python, random-forest, rpy2

I cannot call the R function cforest (package partykit) from python through rpy2.
I suspect this is somehow related to the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35332852/calling-r-functions-in-rpy2-error-argument-is-missing).
It seems to me that the issue is with the formula argument (e.g. formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2). 
It seems that I am doing everything right as I can call the function lm (library stats) which also takes a formula argument.

The code below shows what I am trying to do (set method = 0, = 1, = 2 for different call styles,  = 3 for testing the lm function).

```
method = 1    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import subprocess

import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
import pandas.rpy.common as com
from rpy2.robjects import Formula 


X_train = np.random.rand(500,6)
y_train = np.random.rand(500,1)
ntree = 2
mtry = 5


pk = importr('partykit')
stats = importr('stats')
base = importr('base')

#create dataframes in Python, assign labels consistent with formula below
nx = X_train.shape[1]    
columns = ['y']
for i in range(nx):
    columns.append('x' + str(i))
datatrain = pd.DataFrame(data=np.hstack((y_train, X_train)), columns=columns)

#convert to R dataframe
r_datatrain = com.convert_to_r_dataframe(datatrain)      

#arguments
ctrl = pk.ctree_control(mtry = mtry) 

if method == 0: 
  robjects.r('''
    f <- function(data, ntree, mtry, verbose=FALSE) {
        if (verbose) {
            cat("I am calling f().\n")
        }
    ctrl = ctree_control(mtry = mtry)  
        cforest(formula = y ~ ., data = data, ntree = ntree, control = ctrl)
        }
        ''')
  r_f = robjects.r('f')
  obj = r_f(r_datatrain, ntree, mtry, True)
elif method == 1:
  #arguments  
  obj = pk.cforest('formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2', data = r_datatrain, ntree = ntree, control = ctrl)
elif method == 2:
  fmla = Formula('x1 ~ x2')
  env = fmla.environment
  env['ntree'] = ntree
  env['ctrl'] = ctrl
  env['r_datatrain'] = r_datatrain

  obj = robjects.r('cforest(%s, data = r_datatrain, ntree = ntree, control = ctrl)' %fmla.r_repr())
  #obj = pk.cforest("formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2", data = r_datatrain, ntree = ntree, control = ctrl)
else:
  obj = stats.lm("formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2", data = r_datatrain)

print(obj)
```

Error messages

method = 0

```
I am calling f().
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error in .cnode(1L, data, infl, inputs, weights, ctrl) : 
  R_ExpCovLinstat: y does not have 500 rows

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r2py_issues.py", line 47, in <module>
    obj = r_f(r_datatrain, ntree, mtry, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in .cnode(1L, data, infl, inputs, weights, ctrl) : 
  R_ExpCovLinstat: y does not have 500 rows
```

method = 1

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error: inherits(object, "formula") is not TRUE

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r2py_issues.py", line 50, in <module>
    obj = pk.cforest('formula = y ~ 1 + x1 + x2', data = r_datatrain, ntree = ntree, control = ctrl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error: inherits(object, "formula") is not TRUE
```

method = 2

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py:106: UserWarning: Error in .cnode(1L, data, infl, inputs, weights, ctrl) : 
  R_ExpCovLinstat: y does not have 500 rows

  res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "r2py_issues.py", line 58, in <module>
    obj = robjects.r('cforest(%s, data = r_datatrain, ntree = ntree, control = ctrl)' %fmla.r_repr())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/__init__.py", line 321, in __call__
    res = self.eval(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 178, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 106, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in .cnode(1L, data, infl, inputs, weights, ctrl) : 
  R_ExpCovLinstat: y does not have 500 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting code can require simplifying it enough to isolate sources of problems.

For example, the data frame conversion can be taken out of the question to check is the rest (here the call to learner `cforest`) is working.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
from rpy2.robjects import Formula 

ntree = 2
mtry = 5

pk = importr('partykit')

#arguments
ctrl = pk.ctree_control(mtry = mtry) 

r_datatrain = robjects.r("""
data.frame(y=rnorm(100), 
           x1=rnorm(100), 
           x2=rnorm(100))
""")
obj = pk.cforest(formula = Formula('y ~ 1 + x1 + x2'),
                 data = r_datatrain,
                 ntree = ntree,
                 control = ctrl)
```

That code is working here.

Now you can increasingly add elements from your intended code (e.g., conversion from pandas data frame, dataset closer to your example) until it breaks. That's the exact place where you'll have to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a fix, that is basically using the code of my answer above with the following change:
the line

`#create dataframe directly in R
r_datatrain = robjects.r(""" data.frame(y=rY, x=rX ) """)`

is replaced by the lines

```
#create dataframe directly in R
robjects.r("""
      df <- data.frame(y=rY, 
       x=rX 
      ) 
""")
r_datatrain = robjects.globalenv['df']
```

And you can still call the cforest function with

```
#train
obj = pk.cforest(formula = Formula('y ~ 1 + x.1 + x.2'),
                 data = r_datatrain,
                 ntree = ntree,
                 control = ctrl)
```